# Storing Selected items in Database in a same row

Tags: database, exception, checkedlistbox

I am having a problem.
I have some items in checklist box and i want to add the name of the selected items in a table. But when i use this code.

```
        con.Open();


        foreach (object item in chkOrder.CheckedItems)
        {
            string selectedItems = item.ToString();

            SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();

            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Kitchen (Order_ID,Customer_ID,Reservation_ID,Customer_Name,Charges,Order_Name) VALUES ('" + txtOrderID.Text + "','" + txtCustomerID.Text + "','" + txtReservationID.Text + "','" + txtCustomerName.Text + "','" + allOrders + "',@Order_name)";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Order_Name",selectedItems);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        con.Close();
```

it throws an exception.

Note: "Order_ID" is a primary key.

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_Kitchen'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Kitchen'. The duplicate key value is (1).
The statement has been terminated.'
```

what should i do? 
Please Help.

Comment: The error is quite clear.  You are trying to insert multiple records with the same PK.  WHere is Order_ID incremented?

Comment: @OldProgrammer So what should i do? Sorry i am a beginner in database design.

Answer (score 0):

You can either add parameter AUTO_INCREMENT to your PRIMARY KEY, and not insert it manually, so your database will handle it, or you can increment it in your code.